# How to skip the first start of kotlin StateFlow?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I have a task that takes a long time and want to show its execution progress. So there is the following code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavHostController) {

  val viewModel = hiltViewModel<HomeViewModel>()

  val progress by viewModel.progress.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

  Text(text = "$progress")

}

@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(private val hotHubRepository: HotHubRepository): ViewModel(){
  val progress = flow {
    for(i in 0 .. 1000){
      // Simulate here are some time-consuming network requests
      delay(200)
      emit(i)
    }
  }.stateIn(
    viewModelScope,
    SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
    initialValue = 0
  )
}
```

But what I actually hope is that the user can click the button to manually trigger the task, and now as long as they enter this screen, the task will be executed once.

Which mean's, `collectAsStateWithLifecycle` started the heat flow for the first time, This is not what I want.

So I need to somehow skip the first start of the heat flow. This has two entry points:

1. `collectAsStateWithLifecycle`
2. `Flow.stateIn()`

But I didn't find that these two methods provide ready-made `api` to meet the requirements, what should I do?

Comment: You want progress to start counting only after some action is taken by user?

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov Yes.

Comment: Why not `val progress  = MutableStateFlow(0)`, then update it from another function as you get response from API, `progress.value = X` ?

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov this might be a solution.